# Facebook payments, currency, symbols and formatting

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, in-app-purchase, facebook-javascript-sdk

Going through all the Facebook documentation it would appear there's no way to say to the Facebook SDK *"Give me the price string I need to display to the local user for product x"*.

I'm struggling to believe this is truly the case, as surely this is a basic must have for a company offering an SDK for international purchases.

My question is, is there really no way to get this information from Facebook? They clearly can get it themselves as they display it in their payment dialog. Why do they not provide it to the developer?

If it really is impossible to get the information from Facebook, then how would you recommend I go about dealing with this to display a relevant price to the user.

Comment: The prices in local currency is typically defined by the developer in his Open Graph object. Is there a reason why you want facebook to provide you that information when we ourselves scrape it from the OG specs provided by you.

Comment: @NithyaSivakumar Yes, several reasons. Firstly, you state that if a that if a price is not specified for a currency then you'll handle the conversion. While you provide conversion rates, you don't specify how you round, so even if I knew the currency format I still couldn't guarantee the amounts would match exactly. Secondly it means I have to handle symbols, decimals and formatting, which again, depending how I do it, wont necessarily exactly match what you display. For a consistent flow for the user it makes sense to display a consistent value. That's prob why most other IAP APIs provide it.

Comment: You could retrieve the User's preferred currency along with exchange rates from `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=currency&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN`. Once you have this information, you should be able to calculate the cost by `unit_cost * quantity * userCurreny.usd_exchange_inverse` (as obtained above). Detailed steps can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/payments-tutorial#step3e)

Comment: @NithyaSivakumar Thanks, I've seen that, but that doesn't solve either the rounding or the formatting issues that I've mentioned.

Comment: It looks like this is being solved with the help of an open source JS library [accounting.js](https://github.com/josscrowcroft/accounting.js). Quoting the example of its usage from Sample game in the docs `accounting.formatMoney(price, 
        { symbol: usercurrency.symbol, 
          format:user_currency.pre ? "%s %v" : "%v %s",
          precision: 2
        });` Not too sure if this helps!

Comment: @NithyaSivakumar Does that guarantee to use the same rounding method as Facebook? If you could tell me what rounding method Facebook use, that would be a good start. formatMoney requires me to know the format to pass in all the required parameters, so it doesn't solve the problem. formatMoney does the formatting when told the required format, it doesn't tell me the required format which is a far bigger problem.